# How to convert an ISO date time to local date in angular using moment libary?

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs

I am having angular 5 project and I have a UTC date as string . How can i convert it to local date using moment js . the following is the UTC date string i am having

```
2020-07-31T02:00:00.000+0000
```

appreciate any help

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am giving you an example of converting UTC to Germany's timezone. by using this library:
https://momentjs.com/timezone/

```
const moment = require('moment-timezone');
import 'moment/locale/de';
```

and then in code:

```
let UtcTime = '2020-07-31T02:00:00.000+0000';
let timeZoneOffset = moment(UtcTime).tz("Europe/Berlin").format('Z');
let localTime = moment.utc(UtcTime).utcOffset(timeZoneOffset).format("L");
```

Comment: @knowledgeseeker001 thanks a lot and if it solved the problem then please mark my answer as a solution. thanks.